# c++11. How to get element from tuple without const

Tags: c++11, tuples

I'm trying to do this.

```
int flag = 0;
if(big.size() <= small.size())
  flag = 1; //use float

tuple<long, float> tup (1234.5678, 12341234.1234); 
auto foo = get<flag>(tup);
```

But I get errors:

```
error: the value of 'flag' is not usable in a constant expression
   cout << get<flag>(tup);
```

-and-

```
 note: 'int flag' is not const
 int flag = 0;
```

Comment: my question is mary had a little lamb to that lotr

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of `flag` is not known at compile time, it cannot be used a template parameter.

You'll need to use something like:

```
tuple<long, float> tup (1234.5678, 12341234.1234); 
if ( flag )
{
   auto foo = get<1>(tup);
}
else
{
   auto foo = get<0>(tup);
}
```

Comment: I want foo to exist in the entire scope though

Comment: @djent, You'll have to rethink the logic in your code since what you are attempting won't work.